# Shape object is undefined for ng-map

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, ng-map

I'm currently trying to get a simple app up and running that uses NgMap to overlay custom polygons on a map of the United States. I have been following this example [NgMap Simple Polygon](https://ngmap.github.io/#/!polygon-simple.html). The largest difference I would have compared to this example is I will eventually be transitioning to pulling data from a local json file. Here is my controller code and my html code.

```js
(function () {
    var app = angular.module("testApp", ['ngMap']);
    app.controller("MapController", MapController);
    MapController.$inject = ['$scope', '$timeout', '$http', '$window', 'NgMap'];
    function MapController($scope, $timeout, $http, $window, NgMap) {
        $scope.eastern = getRegionInfo("eastern");
        $scope.florida = [];
        $scope.gateway = [];
        $scope.metroNortheast = [];
        $scope.midAmerica = [];
        $scope.midWest = [];
        $scope.newEnglad = [];
        $scope.northern = [];
        $scope.southern = [];
        $scope.southwest = [];
        $scope.western = [];
        var easternRegion = new google.maps.Polygon({

        });
        function getRegionInfo(region) {
        $http.get("data/regions.txt").success(function (data) {
            $scope[region] = data[region];
        })
        };
    };

})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta name="description" content="Simple Map">
    <meta name="keywords" content="ng-map,AngularJS,center">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <script src="./libraries/angularjs/angular.js">
    </script><script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCi1Dh2ssMKOEwzvOWtDOfQA2gtKMK_yBM&libraries=placeses,visualization,drawing,geometry,places"></script>
    <script src="./views/MapController.js"></script>
    <script src="./libraries/bootstrap/js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.0.0.js"></script>
    <script src="./libraries/ng-map.js"></script>  

    <link href="./libraries/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="testApp">
    <div ng-controller="MapController as App">
        <ng-map center="[40.74, -74.18]"
                map-type-id="TERRAIN">
            <shape name="easternRegion"
                   paths="[
                       [25.774252, -80.190262],
                       [18.466465, -66.118292],
                       [32.321384, -64.75737],
                       [25.774252, -80.190262]
                     ]"
                   stroke-color="#FF0000"
                   stroke-opacity="0.8"
                   stroke-weight="2"
                   fill-color="#FF0000"
                   fill-opacity="0.35">
            </shape>
        </ng-map>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Sadly when I run the current code I receive this error in the console.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
>       at __MapController.vm.addObject (http://localhost:64080/libraries/ng-map.js:67:30)
>       at linkFunc (http://localhost:64080/libraries/ng-map.js:2084:21)
>       at invokeLinkFn (http://localhost:64080/libraries/angularjs/angular.js:9694:9)
>       at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:64080/libraries/angularjs/angular.js:9093:11)
>       at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:64080/libraries/angularjs/angular.js:8397:13)
>       at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:64080/libraries/angularjs/angular.js:9088:24)
>       at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:64080/libraries/angularjs/angular.js:8397:13)
>       at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:64080/libraries/angularjs/angular.js:9088:24)
>       at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:64080/libraries/angularjs/angular.js:8397:13)
>       at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:64080/libraries/angularjs/angular.js:8400:13)

This is the function call where the undefined object is causing the errors.

```js
 /**
     * Add an object to the collection of group
     * @memberof __MapController
     * @function addObject
     * @param groupName the name of collection that object belongs to
     * @param obj  an object to add into a collection, i.e. marker, shape
     */
    vm.addObject = function(groupName, obj) {
      if (vm.map) {
        vm.map[groupName] = vm.map[groupName] || {};
        var len = Object.keys(vm.map[groupName]).length;
        vm.map[groupName][obj.id || len] = obj;

        if (vm.map instanceof google.maps.Map) {
          //infoWindow.setMap works like infoWindow.open
          if (groupName != "infoWindows" && obj.setMap) {
            obj.setMap && obj.setMap(vm.map);
          }
          if (obj.centered && obj.position) {
            vm.map.setCenter(obj.position);
          }
          (groupName == 'markers') && vm.objectChanged('markers');
          (groupName == 'customMarkers') && vm.objectChanged('customMarkers');
        }
      }
    };
```

It seems that the content in the shape tag isn't being properly parsed? I'm not sure about what to do here. Any insight on this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs due the following declaration:

```
<shape name="easternRegion"
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            unknown shape type
```

The point is that `name` attribute of `shape` directive is reserved for the following values (share types):

- `circle`
- `polygon`
- `polyline`
- `rectangle`
- `groundOverlay(or image)`

In your case shape is not getting initialized.

Modified example

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/scripts/ng-map.js"></script>
 
 <div ng-app="ngMap">
        <ng-map  center="[25.774252, -80.190262]" zoom="4"
                map-type-id="TERRAIN">
            <shape name="polygon"
                   paths="[
                       [25.774252, -80.190262],
                       [18.466465, -66.118292],
                       [32.321384, -64.75737],
                       [25.774252, -80.190262]
                     ]"
                   stroke-color="#FF0000"
                   stroke-opacity="0.8"
                   stroke-weight="2"
                   fill-color="#FF0000"
                   fill-opacity="0.35">
            </shape>
        </ng-map>
</div>
```